# How to prove that this impulse response is stable?

Tags: homework, impulse-response

This is the impulse response:

[image]

Can anyone give a detailed method to prove that it is stable or not ?

Comment: Note that an impulse response cannot be stable or unstable. Stability is a property of a system, not its impulse response.

Comment: Have you considered opening your textbook to see what, if anything, it says about the matter? Hint: it might be hidden in a definition such as “A system is said to be BIBO stable if it’s impulse response satisfies.......”

Answer (score 1):

If you check graph of h(t) which is underdamped oscillations presrnt  in 1st and 4th quadrant only. And integration of this h(t) from limits (-infinity to + infinity )  Is finite value. therefore,  system is stable